# JavaScript/jQuery : updating textContent based on element and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the text of child element of an HTML element based on a click event. The user clicks on a span:

```
<span id="button_entitypeople" onclick="toggleentitylist(this.id)" class="fake_link">
    <span class="en">view list</span>
</span>
```

..it displays a div. On doing so, I am trying to get it to rename the `.textContent` of the span from `view list` to `hide list` using `document.getElementById(respdiv).getElementsByClassName('en').textContent`:

```
    function toggleentitylist(clicked_id)
            {{
                var respdiv
                respdiv = clicked_id.replace("button","div");
                if (!document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display | document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display == "none")
                    {{document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display = "inline"; 
                        document.getElementById(respdiv).getElementsByClassName('en')[0].textContent == "hide list";}}
                else {{document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById(respdiv).getElementsByClassName('en')[0].textContent == "show list";}}
            }}
```

While the div is displaying and hiding correctly, the text is not updating.

NB: I have to use `getElementsByClassName` as I will be introducing several different languages.

Many thanks in advance.

```js
function toggleentitylist(clicked_id)
                {{
                    var respdiv
                    respdiv = clicked_id.replace("button","div");
                    if (!document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display | document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display == "none")
                        {{document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display = "inline"; 
                            document.getElementById(respdiv).getElementsByClassName('en')[0].textContent == "hide list";}}
                    else {{document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById(respdiv).getElementsByClassName('en')[0].textContent == "show list";}}
                }}
```

```css
#div_entitypeople{
    display: none;
}

#div_entityplaces{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="button_entitypeople" onclick="toggleentitylist(this.id)" class="fake_link"><span class="en">view list</span></span>
<div id="div_entitypeople">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="Arnald_de_Pencha_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Arnald de Pencha</li>
                                        <li id="Arnald_Roger_PER-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Arnald Roger</li>
                                        <li id="Ava_Sanci_MPX-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ava Sanci</li>
                                        <li id="B_de_Rochafort_SRZ-TA" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">B de Rochafort</li>
                                        <li id="Bernard_Chap_Ladinhac" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Bernard, magister, chaplain of Ladinhac</li>
                                        <li id="Bernard_de_Caux_OP" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Bernard de Caux, OP</li>
                                        <li id="Bernard_de_Quiders_senior_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Bernard de Quiders senior</li>
                                        <li id="Bernard_de_Saint-Esteve_CAZ-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Bernard de Saint-Esteve</li>
                                        <li id="Bertrand_de_Quiders_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Bertrand de Quiders</li>
                                        <li id="Bertrand_Marti_H" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Bertrand Marti</li>
                                        <li id="Braida_de_Mont_Server_SRZ-TA" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Braida de Mont Server</li>
                                        <li id="Cecilia_Roger_nee_de_Mont_Server_PER-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Cecilia Roger</li>
                                        <li id="Corba_de_Pereille_PER-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Corba de Pereille</li>
                                        <li id="Dominic_de_Catalonia" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Dominic de Catalonia</li>
                                        <li id="Ermengarde_de_Caucer_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ermengarde de Caucer</li>
                                        <li id="Ermengarde_de_Mazerol_GAJ-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ermengarde de Mazerol</li>
                                        <li id="Estolt_de_Rochavila_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Estolt de Rochavila</li>
                                        <li id="Fauressa_del_Mas_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Fauressa del Mas</li>
                                        <li id="Ferrier_OP" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ferrier, OP</li>
                                        <li id="Francesca_de_la_Ylha_MPX-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Francesca de la Ylha</li>
                                        <li id="Galharda_de_Romengos_RMG-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Galharda de Romengos</li>
                                        <li id="Galharda_del_Mas_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Galharda del Mas</li>
                                        <li id="Geralda_de_Rochafort_SRZ-TA" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Geralda de Rochafort</li>
                                        <li id="Guilabert_de_Castres_H" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilabert de Castres</li>
                                        <li id="Guilhelma_Canast_de_Paracol_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhelma Canast de Paracol</li>
                                        <li id="Guilhelma_Meta_nee_del_Mas_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhelma Meta née del Mas</li>
                                        <li id="Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem Canast-Brus</li>
                                        <li id="Guilhem_de_la_Ylha_MPX-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem de la Ylha</li>
                                        <li id="Guilhem_de_Rochafort_SRZ-TA" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem de Rochafort</li>
                                        <li id="Guilhem_del_Mas_Junior_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem del Mas junior</li>
                                        <li id="Guilhem_del_Mas_Senior_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Guilhem del Mas senior</li>
                                        <li id="heretics_not_named" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">heretics not named</li>
                                        <li id="heretics_unknown_2f" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">2 unknown female heretics</li>
                                        <li id="heretics_unknown_3f" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">3 unknown female heretics</li>
                                        <li id="heretics_unknown_m" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">unknown male heretics</li>
                                        <li id="Johan_Cambiaire_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Johan Cambiaire</li>
                                        <li id="Maria_de_Quiders_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Maria de Quiders</li>
                                        <li id="Marquesa_de_Rochafort_SRZ-TA" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Marquesa de Rochafort</li>
                                        <li id="mother_of_Dominic_de_Catalonia" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">mother of Dominic de Catalonia</li>
                                        <li id="Na_Fornier_de_Pereille_PER-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Na Fornier de Pereille</li>
                                        <li id="Na_Laureta_MPX-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Na Laureta</li>
                                        <li id="others_unrecalled" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">many others unrecalled</li>
                                        <li id="P_Audoys_MPX-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">P Audoys</li>
                                        <li id="P_Bernard_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">P Bernard</li>
                                        <li id="P_de_las_Combas_QLE-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">P de las Combas</li>
                                        <li id="P_Raimund_Roi_MPX-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">P. Raimund Roi</li>
                                        <li id="Peire_de_Fogars_LAV-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Peire de Fogars</li>
                                        <li id="Peire_de_Mazerol_GAJ-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Peire de Mazerol</li>
                                        <li id="Peire_Faure_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Peire Faure</li>
                                        <li id="Peire_Fresapa_NOT" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Peire Fresapa, notary</li>
                                        <li id="Pelegrina_de_Mont_Server_nee_del_Mas_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Pelegrina de Mont Server née del Mas</li>
                                        <li id="Ponca_de_Vilar_QLE-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ponca de Vilar</li>
                                        <li id="Raimund_Canast_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Raimund Canast</li>
                                        <li id="Raimund_de_Pereille_PER-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Raimund de Pereille</li>
                                        <li id="Raimund_Sanci_MPX-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Raimund Sanci</li>
                                        <li id="Raimunda_de_Cuc_CMS-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Raimunda de Cuc</li>
                                        <li id="Raimunda_de_Mont_Server_SRZ-TA" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Raimunda de Mont Server</li>
                                        <li id="Ransana_de_Fanjeaux_FJX-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ransana de Fanjeaux</li>
                                        <li id="Sylvestre_Chap_Verfeil" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Sylvestre, chaplain of Verfeil</li>
                                        <li id="W_de_Mirepoix_PAM-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">W de Mirepoix</li>
                                        <li id="Ysarn_de_Fanjeaux_FJX-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ysarn de Fanjeaux</li>
                                        <li id="Ysarn_de_Mont_Server_SRZ-TA" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ysarn de Mont Server</li>
                                        <li id="Ysarn_de_Vilar_QLE-AR" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">Ysarn de Vilar</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
<br/>                            
<span id="button_entityplaces" onclick="toggleentitylist(this.id)" class="fake_link"><span class="en">view list</span></span>
               <div id="div_entityplaces">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="home_in_Queille" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus in Queillé</span><span class="fr">domus à Queillé</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_Dominic_de_Catalonia" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of Dominic de Catalonia</span><span class="fr">domus de Dominic de Catalonia</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_Guilabert_de_Castre" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of Guilabert de Castre</span><span class="fr">domus de Guilabert de Castre</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_Guilhem_Canast-Brus" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of Guilhem Canast-Brus</span><span class="fr">domus de Guilhem Canast-Brus</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_Guilhem_del_Mas_Sr_MSP" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of Guilhem del Mas senior</span><span class="fr">domus de Guilhem del Mas senior</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_Na_Fornier_de_Pereille" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of Na Fornier de Pereille</span><span class="fr">domus de Na Fornier de Pereille</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_Na_Laureta" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of Na Laureta</span><span class="fr">domus de Na Laureta</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_P_de_las_Combas" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of P. de las Comabas</span><span class="fr">domus de P. de las Comabas</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_Peire_Faure_MSP" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of Peire Faure</span><span class="fr">domus de Peire Faure</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="home_of_Raimund_Canast_MSP-AU" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span class="en">domus of Bernard and Raimund Canast</span><span class="fr">domus de Bernard et Raimund Canast</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="Lavelanet_Ariege" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span>Lavelanet</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="Mirepoix_Ariege" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span>Mirepoix</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="Montsegur_Ariege" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span>Montségur</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="Pamiers_Ariege" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span>Pamiers</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="Pereille_Ariege" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span>Péreille</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id="Saissac_Aude" class="highlight-entities" onclick="highlightEntities(this)">
                                            <name><span>Saissac</span></name>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I vote to close this question: it is a mere typo: `==` should be `=` (for assignment)

Comment: @medyas demonstrated clearly that the problem was not a typo. They also provided a response which clarified the problem in my code logic and provided a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easier to use jQuery for this, you select the element then find sub element. Also in you function your trying to find the span with class 'button_entitypeople' which your using the 'respdiv' variable but you already replaced the button with div so its not valid, you will have to find the element with the 'clicked_id' then find the span with 'en' class.

```
function toggleentitylist(clicked_id)
        {
            var respdiv
            respdiv = clicked_id.replace("button","div");
            if (!document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display | document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display == "none"){

                    document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display = "inline"; 
                    $("#"+clicked_id).find($("."+'en')).text("Hide list");
                }
            else {
                document.getElementById(respdiv).style.display = "none";
                    $("#"+clicked_id).find($("."+'en')).text("Show list");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Works brilliant, thanks! Also, thanks very much for the helpful understanding the errors in the code I wrote - it helps me a lot.

Answer (score -2):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a node list. Node lists don't have a `textContent` property, individual nodes do. So this:

```
document.getElementById(respdiv).getElementsByClassName('en').textContent == "show list";
```

won't work;

You'll need to isolate one of the nodes from the node list.

You can do that by passing an index:

```
document.getElementById(respdiv).getElementsByClassName('en')[0].textContent == "show list";
```

Comment: I added the index  `[0]` to the code in the original post per your suggestion, but it doesn't change the outcome. Snippet runs an error.I may not fully understand what you intended to say...thanks.

Comment: In fact running the snippet embedded above will show the errors directly inline, but here it is: `{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 147,
  "colno": 93
}`

Comment: So, the error has told you the problem `document.getElementById(respdiv).getElementsByClassName('en')` is not returning any nodes in its node list, so `[0]` doesn't find anything.

Comment: Don't know why this answer is down voted. It correctly states why `.textContent` won't work on the result of `getElementsByClassName()`.